# Lotus notes Document appears both in Inbox and SentItem

Tags: lotus-notes

I have created a CPP COM dll to read a EML File and add it to Lotus notes NSF file. Using MIMEContent to create the mails but the problem is when i am adding the document to folder view $Inbox same mail is copied $Sent Item Folder. Below is the code

```
           newdoc.Save();
           Folder.FolderAddDocument(newdoc);


    // Color the background
    Folder.SetBackgroundColor(LNCOLOR_LIGHT_GRAY);

    // Change the heading display
    Folder.SetHeadingDisplay(LNVFHEADINGDISPLAY_BEVELED);

    Folder.Save();
    //cout<<"ReadViews4"<<endl;
    Folder.Close();
    //cout<<"ReadViews5"<<endl;
    newdoc.Close();
```

Thanks and Regards,
Haseena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the selection formula for the Sent view of the 8.5.x mail template:

> SELECT DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S";
>   ExcludeFromView))

If the imported mail document should appear as a incoming mail, it must have a DeliveredDate field with a date (which then means that it will not appear in the Sent view).

I can not see how you set the properties of the mail document, since your code example only contains `newdoc.Save()` and `newdoc.Close()`.

So have a look at the properties of your imported mail, and have a look at the CPP code that sets the properties of the mail document.

Comment: i am reading the eml as mime string through chilkat mail and adding it to notes document 
 
MIMEStreamWrite(( unsigned char*)ch_mimeContent,strlen(ch_mimeContent),hMIMEStream);
if ( error == MIME_STREAM_IO )
{
printf("MIMEStreamPutLine error.\n");
MIMEStreamClose(hMIMEStream);
return ;
}
// itemize the mime stream to the note
error = MIMEStreamItemize( handle,NULL, 0, MIME_STREAM_ITEMIZE_FULL,hMIMEStream);

Comment: How should i make it save it inbox folder and not appear in sent item.How should i make it save it inbox folder and not appear in sent item.

Comment: You need to set the required DeliveredDate field to the date the mail was received.

Comment: Also, either of the following will exclude it from the Sent view: newdoc.replaceItemValue("PostedDate","")
or newdoc.replaceItemValue("ExcludeFromView","S")

Comment: I tried setting the Delivered Date, but when i change the system date format the date in the mail appear to be ****. How can i make it generic for all datetime format?

Answer (score 0):

Like others said:
Create the field "DilveredDate". Replace its value with e.g. Today.

```
DateTime timenow = session.createDateTime("Today");
timenow.setNow();
newdoc.replaceItemValue("DeliveredDate", timeNow);
```

And your document will not show up in the sendTo-View.